# Array-like objects and arrays not logged like arrays if the console is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wefaf/3/edit) where, to answer another question, I build an array-like object :

```
function myCollection() {
  var items = [], r = {}
  function myPush(value){
      value += 'bar'
      r[items.length]=value;
      items.push(value)    
  }
  Object.defineProperty(r, "splice", {value:[].splice});
  Object.defineProperty(r, "slice", {value:[].slice});
  Object.defineProperty(r, "length", {
    get : function(){ return items.length}
  });
  Object.defineProperty(r, "myPush", {value:myPush});
  return r;
}

var fooCollection = myCollection();
fooCollection.myPush('foo');
console.log(fooCollection); // logs ["foobar"] 
fooCollection.myPush('Ba');
console.log(fooCollection); // logs ["foobar", "Babar"] 

fooCollection.myPush('wzouing');
console.log(fooCollection.slice(-2)); //logs ["Babar", "wzouingbar"] 
console.log(fooCollection[1]); // logs Babar
```

If you hit the **Run with JS** button on Chromium with the console open, you get this :

[image]

The very curious thing is that if you hit the button while the console is closed you get this (you see it after having reopened the console, of course) :

[image]

Is that a known bug ? A feature ? A grey zone ? Is there a workaround ?

*Note : sometimes, on Chrome/linux (not Chromium) I get something weirder : existing logs are changed when closing and reopening the console. They can go from the array like form to the folded form. *

Comment: I think you'd get better responses on chrome's bug-tracker/mailing list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software behavior and not actual programming

Comment: Can you kindly let me know what is the expected output.

Comment: The reason why it always logs `Object[3]` (instead of `Object[1]`/`Object[2]` when `fooCollection` was smaller) is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the very specific unspecified behavior of a browser in a rare case.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this behaviour could be an intended one to save memory/performance, since resolving/printing runtime objects is a pretty expensive task.

If you really need an unwrapped info, I'd suggest using

```
console.dir( myStuff );
```

Or, alternatively, for arrays there is a new

```
console.table( myArray );
```

TIP: `console.dir` is is also the way to log the object contents in Internet Explorer, as opposed to it's default `log()` output of `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like an issue at: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801

Seems it's already fixed in webkit.

Comment: That rather sounds like [bug #35316](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316)? This question asks about logging when the whole *console* is closed, not about modifying objects that have been logged (while the console was open)

Answer (score 0):

> The very curious thing is that if you log an object while the console is closed, you don't get the expanded (array-like) view (after having reopened the console, of course).
>
> Is that a known bug? A feature?

A feature, I'd guess. The console is optimized for performance while it is not opened, and therefore does not compute that expanded view of the object

> Is there a workaround?

Have a look at [How can I change the default behavior of console.log? (*Error console in safari, no add-on*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389069/1048572). You'd have the [typical lazyness problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572) anyway. Logging JSON strings should help.