# Why do I have a not defined scope ? angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to 'extract' a value from scope. However I get an error that is not defined, through I don't understand why. This is from Chrome dev

```
  console.log($scope.auth)
  console.log($scope)
```

The first one prints "undefined" and the second one prints as follows. I expected $scope.auth to print the object

```
auth: Object
Owner: "agent2"
Role: "coldCalling"
```

Is there any reason for this ?

```
$$childScopeClass {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: Object…}
$$childHead: null
$$childScopeClass: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: null
$$watchers: null
$id: "002"
$parent: Scope
auth: Object
   Owner: "agent2"
   Role: "coldCalling"
__proto__: Object
this: $$childScopeClass
__proto__: Scope
```

Comment: Maybe the auth object did not exist when you ran console.log. It would still appear in the second call because console.log sort of shows the current state of variable when you expand it. Try putting a timeout on it and see what happens.

Comment: It's quit odd because everything seems to work http://plnkr.co/edit/9OrxbqY3MPwtGGfSR32T?p=preview could you give us more of your code ? If auth is adde by a service to the scope, the you should update it inside a .then or .success block as it's asynchronous

Comment: @ex0ns I'm pretty sure this is what happens: http://plnkr.co/edit/uqJVzfYNoJ0KCRGZawdW?p=preview

Comment: You added a timeout, so 'Auth' is not set when calling console.log, could you give use the controller which loads Auth in your case ?

Comment: Timeout is just a fake replacement (or simulation if you will, but that's not the point) for any async call... see what happens in the console, auth is present in the full $scope object and undefined in $scope.auth log. That's the nature of the console. Explained it in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show the full code, but it's probably happening because the auth object did not exist when you ran console.log (you're probably fetching it from an async service call, etc.). It would still appear in the `console.log($scope)` call because console shows the current state of a variable when you expand it. So by the time you expand the `$scope` variable in the console, its `auth` object is defined and set.

Here's an example with a timeout (to simulate any async event):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.auth = {'Owner': 'Test', 'Role': 'Role'};
}, 1000);
console.log($scope.auth);   // undefined
console.log($scope);        // auth object exists when you expand it in the console
```

See the full example here (check the console): http://plnkr.co/edit/uqJVzfYNoJ0KCRGZawdW?p=preview

Also, you'll find some nice explanations related to that here: [How can I change the default behavior of console.log? (*Error console in safari, no add-on*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

---

So, the bottom line: you **won't** be able to "extract" that scope value simply because it's unavailable at that point. Show some more code and we'll help you figure out when it becomes available.