# JS object, need explanation of what's happening and why

Tags: javascript, json, object

This is the code for `Pet`:

```
function Pet() {
    this.vitals = new Vitals();
}

function Vitals() {
    this.hunger = 5;
    this.thirst = 0;
    this.emotions = {
        happy: true,
        sad: true
    }
}
```

Below is the calling and so forth:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pet = new Pet();
    console.log(pet);
    pet.vitals.emotions.happy = false;
    console.log(pet);
});
```

This is what I get from the console:

[image: console results]

**Question:** Why is `happy` `false` in both readouts, and not just the second one?

Comment: See [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `console.log` can update data already printed if the underlying object reference is updated afterwards. Try to create another reference called `pet2` to see the trick.

By the way, you should to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389177/985949) and [this](https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/issues/19).

Comment: Interesting.  Someone suggested stringifying in that link and that seems to capture the state of execution, rather than it's current state, so that link was quite helpful. :)

Comment: Indeed, the subject is interesting :)