# Get currentPath in ApplicationRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

It's entirely possible that I'm not quite understanding the order of instantiation of controllers when a route is entered, but I'm attempting to get `currentPath` in `beforeModel` in my ApplicationRoute and struggling. The odd thing is when I log the route, I can see a property called `controller` in it...

[image]

```
beforeModel: function(transition) {

    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.controller); // undefined
    console.log(this.get('controller')); // undefined

    // this too
    console.log(this.controllerFor('application'));
    console.log(this.controllerFor('application').currentPath); // undefined
    console.log(this.controllerFor("application").get("currentPath")); // undefined

},
```

But `this.controller` is undefined. As you can see in the log output, currentPath is indeed set on that property, and that's what I want!

I noted that `controller` clearly isn't defined until after the router has instantiated the controller. So the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controller) is somewhat clear in that in `willTransition`, `this.controller` *is* defined.

The controller property seems to get defined in [`setup`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.8.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L974) so I'm super confused as to how I can see it in `beforeModel`. How can I get `currentPath` in `beforeModel` in `ApplicationRoute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `console.log` with an object returns a reference to said object. So it's not a snapshot of the object at the time of the log.

[This little trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364821/53653) got me the object in the state when logged:

```
console.log($.extend({}, this));
```