# reverse() on json obj array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reverse

why my json array is not reversing ?

```
var arr = [{"myId":"7d8f72c3f070736caf399df0a8211f5ei324410"},  
           {"myId":"963d01cfa92a4f9d3cb755c7d3822e68i1744695"},  
           {"myId":"5994f40a1b2fd9ff69d4e4551d18766ci2977900"},  
           {"myId":"25bb4db94056ec38ba7ed1ee96e90006i2956275"},  
           {"myId":"7720ec9200d5a6f5d16a447bc5ff7f2ci1080950"},  
           {"myId":"f8a21d90a3adb464e7c3782471e1455bi3087305"}];

console.log(arr);
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr);  // not reversing :-(
```

Can anyone suggest me why my array is not reversing ?

http://jsfiddle.net/rkq8cxma/

Comment: @A.B I think it's printing reverse for both.

Comment: @Mritunjay see my answer and demo it is not :? strange

Comment: your code works as expected, just that console use reference to object: http://jsfiddle.net/rkq8cxma/1/

Comment: Related: [console.log object at current state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine see output below

```js
var arr = [{"myId":"7d8f72c3f070736caf399df0a8211f5ei324410"},{"myId":"963d01cfa92a4f9d3cb755c7d3822e68i1744695"},{"myId":"5994f40a1b2fd9ff69d4e4551d18766ci2977900"},{"myId":"25bb4db94056ec38ba7ed1ee96e90006i2956275"},{"myId":"7720ec9200d5a6f5d16a447bc5ff7f2ci1080950"},{"myId":"f8a21d90a3adb464e7c3782471e1455bi3087305"}];
console.log(arr);
arr.forEach(function(e){
    document.body.innerHTML+=e.myId+"<br/>";
})
arr.reverse();
document.body.innerHTML+="----------------<br/>";
arr.forEach(function(e){
    document.body.innerHTML+=e.myId+"<br/>";
})
```