# AngularJS UI Router - $state.current.name is empty when using templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am using ui router for Angular and trying to get the name of the current state.

After 3 days working on it, I found out that it is empty when I use templateUrl. 
After changing it to template: 'test', state name magically appears...

Is it possible to make it work?
[Here is the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUWyTM1ei5WVW03K2WqD)

```
Code on above link
```

Comment: Sorry about that "enter code here" I missclicked it and now I can't edit my post.

Comment: In the plunker launch the preview in a separate window, and it works like a charm. :)

Comment: @Arth what the is problem, I can see `$state.current.name` in console?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A $watch is needed here, because it's all asynchronous we can't rely on timing:

```
myApp.controller('navCtrl', ['$state', '$scope','$timeout', function($state, $scope, $timeout){
    $scope.currState = $state;
    console.log("This one have some objects: ");
    console.log('by reference:', $scope.currState);
    console.log('by value:', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.currState)));

    // console.log("But when I want to access name its empty: ");
    // $timeout(function() {
    //    console.log($state.current.name);
    // });

    // use this instead:
    $scope.$watch('currState.current.name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
    });  
}]);
```

The `console.log('by reference:', $scope.currState);` does work because that uses a reference to the object. By the time we see it in the console the object is already changed.

Compare with the output of `console.log('by value:', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.currState)));` above, which freezes the output at the point of execution. You'll find an empty `$state.current.name`.

Also see: [How can I change the default behavior of console.log? (*Error console in safari, no add-on*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Comment: This works great!! Used it to change body style based on current state.