# How to access variable in angular scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope

When I insert `console.log($scope)` into my code, I get the following result:

```
$get.k.$new.a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[4], $$listeners: Object…}
$$childHead: null
$$childScopeClass: null
$$childTail: null
$$listenerCount: Object
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: null
$$prevSibling: $get.k.$new.a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass
$$watchers: Array[4]
$id: "005"
$parent: Object
Bad: false
Good: true
Search: function () {
address: "63146"
focus: "63146"
this: $get.k.$new.a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass
__proto__: Object
```

The variable I am interested in is `Good: true`. However, when I call `console.log($scope.Good)` on the next line, it returns `false`.

How do I call the above "Good" variable that returns true in the console?

edit:
**Controller**

```
app.controller('locationController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Good = false;
    $scope.Bad = false;

    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 38.68, lng: -90.46 },
        zoom: 8
    };

    var image = {
        url: 'app/assets/img/marker.png'
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);
    $scope.Search = function () {
        $scope.Good = false;
        $scope.Bad = false;
        var address = $scope.address;
        var radius = parseInt(50, 10) * 1000;
        var marker_start = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: 38.688757, lng: -90.464391 },
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: ""
        });

        var fill = '#fff';
        var populationOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#66FF99',
            strokeOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: fill,
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.68, -90.46),
            radius: 80000
        };

        var lat = '';
        var lng = '';
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var marker_user = null;

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                marker_user = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: "Your Location"
                });

                if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker_user.getPosition(), marker_start.getPosition()) < 80000)
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.Good = true; });
                else
                    $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.Bad = true; });
            }
        });

        console.log($scope);
        console.log($scope.Good);
        console.log($scope.Bad);
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    };
});
```

Comment: Show us your controllers

Comment: Edited to include controller.

Comment: This is a common problem when you log an `Object` to the console. The console is showing you the up to the moment values of that object. I'll try to find an existing answer that explains why you see what you see, and link back here if I do.

Comment: Here is an [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state) for why the console shows what it does. It may not solve the actual problem you're debugging. (EDIT: In fact, you're setting `$scope.Good` correctly in your callback, so there's probably no other issue w/your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Good` becomes true only *after* the callback function passed to `geocoder.geocode()` has been called. But you're printing it *before* it has been called, right after having *asked* the geocoder to geocode.

1. ask the geocoder to geocode. This sends an HTTP request to Google
2. print Good: it's still false
3. when the response from Google comes in, the callback is executed and Good becomes true

Comment: Note that he prints `$scope` and `$scope.Good` to the console all BEFORE the callback has been executed. See my comment above...

Comment: Err yes, that's pretty much exactly what my answer says.

Comment: No, if it were the problem you speak of the value shown when he logs just the `$scope` would also be false. In this case it shows true. I'm suggesting that [this type of problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state) is happening.

Comment: @SunilD. just because console is live reference not snapshot doesn't make the answer wrong... answer explains what the actual execution flow is

Comment: @charlietfl  but look at the last 4-5 lines of the controller. The OP seems to be asking why do I see true when I log `$scope` and false when I log `$scope.Good`? Those two statements are executed sequentially, the callback cannot effect the value between those two statements.

Comment: @SunilD.  simplest thing if you don't agree....is right up another answer. If you think OP needs to be told to move the logging statement, and that they can't interpret it from this answer, put it in your answer.