# Why I am getting wrong output when I modify the following Javascript object code?

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript code.

```
var option={
  value:'',
  desc:{
   en:'',
   hn:''
  }
};
option.value='15';
option.desc.en='hello';
option.desc.hn='world'; 

console.log(option);

option.value='25';
option.desc.hn='India';

console.log(option);
```

This gives the output-

`object {value:25,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"India"}}}`

`object {value:25,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"India"}}}`

Instead of

`object {value:15,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"world"}}}`

`object {value:25,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"India"}}}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state

Answer (score 0):

the output diff with different browser. I got the 
object {value:15,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"world"}}}
object {value:25,object {desc:{en:"hello",hn:"India"}}}
through chrome.

Comment: Try with Mozilla.. Do you have the reason why its behaving like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Chales Tuang mentioned, I got the expected output on

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgn0m4fh/)

```
var option={
  value:'',
  desc:{
   en:'',
   hn:''
 }
};
option.value='15';
option.desc.en='hello';
option.desc.hn='world'; 

console.log(option);

option.value='25';
option.desc.hn='India';

console.log(option);
```

The only explanation I could possibly think of for the case where you get same output in each call to console.log, is that the browser is applying the principle that objects are live in Javascript, as shown by Stoyan Stefanov in his book [Object Oriented Javascript](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/1847194141)

As a result, the when you call console.log, it sees the latest, up-to-date property(ies) of the object, even though the object was augmented after the call, in as much as the update is within the scope of the call, it just grabs the current updated state of the object.

That's my thought on this, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a bug in WebKit browsers (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44720)

Instead of logging the entire object,try to log the particular value, you will get the expected result..

```
 console.log(option.desc.hn);
```

Or try JSON.stringify

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(option));
```

JS Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/t744ohog/2/