# JavaScript: Storing objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please explain the results of the following example, especially the cases 1.2 and 2.2:

Shouldn't be the output of case 1.2: `Object[0] {foo:"a"}` ?
Shouldn't be the output of case 2.2: `Object[0] {foo:"b"}` ?

```
var obj = {foo:'a'};    // Define an object
var arr = [obj];        // Store the object within an array
console.log(obj);       // Case 1.1: Object {foo:"a"}
console.log(arr);       // Case 1.2: Object[0] {foo:"c"}

function Foo(o){ o.foo = 'b'; };
Foo(obj);               // Change the object's property by using a function
console.log(obj);       // Case 2.1: Object {foo:"b"}
console.log(arr);       // Case 2.2: Object[0] {foo:"c"}

arr[0].foo = 'c';       // Change the object's property by using the array
console.log(obj);       // Case 3.1: Object {foo:"c"}
console.log(arr);       // Case 3.2: Object[0] {foo:"c"}
```

Comment: the console might defer evaluation till you expand the array. try using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: The `console.log()` facility can do weird things sometimes. It's not always synchronous (which, to me, is a serious problem).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state