# How can I dynamically add to this object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the object `msg.data` which holds:

```
{    
"user_id": 1,
"success": "true"
}
```

I would like to add `name` to this list:

```
{    
"user_id": 1,
"success": "true",
"name" : "giri"
}
```

I have tried:

```
msg.data.name = "giri";
```

but when I print out `msg.data`, I always get the initial result.

Would someone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try: `message.data.name`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao nope, this is an object not an array

Comment: mag.data.name = "giri"

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I get the error `msg.data.push is not a function`

Comment: what's the `typeof msg.data`, Object?

Comment: @Giri Its invalid.. sorry for that!! Try this once `msg.data["name"]="giri"`

Comment: You might have a scoping issue if FrankerZ's answer doesn't work; we can't know without seeing more code, particularly where you're actually *using* the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon `typeof msg.data`. If it is an object, then it should be straightforward to add newer members using `.` You can add name property as follows

```
msg.data.name = "haseeb";
```

if it is a json string then you need to parse it into and object and then add property using `.`

```
var myobject = JSON.parse(msg.data);
myobject.name = "haseeb";
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in the console, and it works for me:

```
msg = {};
msg.data = {    
"user_id": 1,
"success": "true"
};
msg.data.name = "giri";
msg; //Since we're in the console, this will output the variable. Otherwise use console.log(msg) to output the contents.
```

Ensure you have no typos, and nothing else is modifying the object. Do a `console.dir` before and right after your statement. Also, be aware that the console may display the incorrect object at the time (If you use `console.log`), since it's showing you the current object by reference (Which may be different at the time you view the console). You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state) post for a bit more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

`msg = {};` or `msg.data = {}` it  works as an object

and you can add any variable dynamicly

```
msg.firstvar=""
msg.Secondvar=""
msg.Thirdvar=""

msg.data.firstvar=""
msg.data.Secondvar=""
msg.data.Thirdvar=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it,

I assume the variable be a dymanic object created,
a response on ajax

```
var msg = {
    "user_id" : 1,
    "success" : true
};

if (msg.name == undefined ) {

    Object.defineProperty(msg, 'name', {
        value : 'giri',
        writable : false, // if you want the value to be change
        enumerable : true // if you want the object to property to be iterated
    });
}
```

Read also [Object Define Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

> but when I print out msg.data, I always get the initial result.

Means that msg.data doesn't actually exist, it yields "undefined" (most likely).

Use debugger (or print out in console) the contents of msg.