# Why does Chrome console.log show my variable updated before it is updated?

Tags: javascript, datatables, google-chrome-devtools

**Disclaimer:** This is slightly mind-boggling, it's been a long night and I'm not a native speaker - so pls. forgive if the description is unclear. Pls. just comment and I'll try to clarify :)

I am trying to make a Datatables-table editable, and so far it looks quite good. But I got a surprise when I looked at the results in detail and it turned out that my little function to clone a row also modified the original row!

for a repro, pls. have a look at the saved page which I stored @ http://mbaas.de/edperm.html. Open the console, click on the "speichern"-Button: this will just log the data to the console. (*Just to make sure the values are what we expect*). Now click on the small icon to the left of the "7" in the last row: this is supposed to clone that row (JS-Function `cloneRow` which I'll show later) and watch the console-output: check the array that is printed immediately after "cloneRow!" - as you see in the code, nothing has been done to update data, yet data[3][0] has been changed already! And, BTW, line3 should be totally unaffected anyway by this update - I want to read that row, change the id and append it.

So, here is the code of cloneRow:

```
function cloneRow(arg)
{
    var oTable = $("#tabPerm").DataTable();
    console.log('cloneRow!');
    var d1a = oTable.data();
    console.log(d1a);
    arg=$(arg).closest('tr');
    var d = oTable.row(arg).data();
    console.log("Vor Zuweisung d");
    var d2a = oTable.data();
    console.log(d2a);

    d[0]=-7;
    console.log("Nach Zuweisung d");
    var d3a = oTable.data();
    console.log(d3a);
    oTable.row.add(d).draw();
    var d4a = oTable.data();
    console.log(d4a);
}
```

What is the explanation of this effect? Is it timing of console-output or what...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state

Comment: Thank you - that sounds very plausible. BUT I have now update cloneRow to assign different (distinct) variables for every logging - and still that line3 is shown modified right at the start of cloneRow. (variable `d1a`)

Comment: @MBaas: It doesn't matter that you're using different variable names. It matters that `oTable.data();` returns the same object every time.

Comment: @Bergi But oTable is not supposed to return the same object every time - this data is being changed with the row.add-statement.

Comment: @MBaas: Yes, the object is changed (mutated, its properties are changed), but I'm pretty sure it's still the same object. And at least, you can try `data[3] == d && d == data[2]` (or whatever row you selected). Notice that you *did not clone it* - it's still the same row, appearing twice in the table.

Comment: Ok, finally I got it. I was not aware of this behaviour when assigning object. Thanks for explaning!