# Unable to push values in Array

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code. I am unable to push the `Metric` variable to `MetricArray`.  What is the issue? Updated to add a loop and a statement that clears the array.

PS: This isn't the complete code and I can't put the exact code here. I fetch different values of `Metric` and push them to `ArrayOfMetric.MetricArray`. Then I reset `ArrayOfMetric.MetricArray` and fetch another set of `Metric` values and so on. So I need a way to reset `ArrayOfMetric`. Please also explain why the initial values are getting wiped out when I am printing it while the array had a snapshot of those values.

Is there a way to reset the array without loosing initial values?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var Metric = {
        "Code": "",
        "Name": "",
        "Value": ""
    };

    var ArrayOfMetric = {
        "MetricArray": []
    };

    Metric.Code = "ABC";
    Metric.Name = "AB Corporation";
    Metric.Value = 1245.67;

    ArrayOfMetric.MetricArray.push(Metric);

    console.log(Metric);        // Prints correct values                 
    console.log(ArrayOfMetric); // Shows MetricArray empty

    ArrayOfMetric.MetricArray = [];   
}
```

Comment: works fine https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/kor3z7bp/

Comment: @Alexander yes, that works. Please see updated question.

Comment: you're clearing the MetricArray at the end of the loop ...

Comment: @JaromandaX is there a way to reset the array without loosing earlier values or create a new instance of ArrayOfMetric? I don't know JS that well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log object at current state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Comment: You seem surprised that the array is empty - it's final state will always be empty

Comment: But isn't console.log is firing when array had values?

Comment: @Forkmohit No, that's the point. See the link to "possible duplicate". References can be nasty sometimes.

Comment: Yes, Thanks to @Siguza. That cleared some misconceptions.

Comment: @Siguza I tried creating a  temp variable. But that assignment also seems to be referential. I am not getting What to do in my case?

Comment: @Forkmohit Replace `ArrayOfMetric.MetricArray = [];` with `ArrayOfMetric = {MetricArray: []};`.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you have a syntax error where `Console` should be `console`

Comment: -Filype Thanks for pointing out. Please see updated question.