# Unable to iterate through an array. Showing length as zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, highcharts

I want to get the first object as given in the image-
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DILAC.png)

But the array length is showing zero. But when I run typeof it shows object. It is an array of object or something else?
This is the code to get the first object

```
(this.trendChart.yAxis[0]['series'])[0]
```

**EDIT**
I want the first object from series array - [image]

**EDIT**
On using (this.trendChart.yAxis[0]['series']) i'm getting the value as shown in first image.

Comment: `typeof` always says `object` for arrays.

Comment: Are you filling the array using an async function? You're probably checking the length before it has completed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Your question generally needs more detail. The length of which array is zero? What value are you running `typeof` against, an array or an element of the array?

Comment: @backtick typeof this.trendChart.yAxis[0]['series'] gives object.

Comment: Probably best to update the question with this context if you get a chance. Barmar's comment here is relevant. `typeof` for any array is always `'object'`, it doesn't matter if the array is empty or not.

Comment: I was just checking what is the type. I want to get the first object. @Barmar

Comment: As I said above, you're probably trying to get the first object before the async function has assigned it.

Comment: But you're viewing it in the console after it has been updated. The console has a live link to the array, so it updates as the array is filled in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277332/javascript-console-log-reporting-object-properties-incorrectly

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor?

Comment: You can simulate async operations for example by using `setTimeout`.

Comment: can you please help in this highcharts stock tool problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67311156/15500072) @ppotaczek

Answer (score 1):

Showing us the whole object structure in text instead of an image would help. From your image, try `this.trendChart.yAxis.series[0]`.

Comment: try showing us the whole structure of the `this.trendChart` object in text

Comment: `this.trendChart.yAxis[0].series[0]` is equivalent to what they used in the code.

Comment: that's true, and it's highly it's possible you're right and he's using that variable before it's initialized properly, but he mentioned that `typeof` shows it as an object so it might just be a syntax issue. In any case the only way to know is if we see the whole object.