# save chart button of stock tool chart not working in highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

On clicking save charts button of stock tool chart nothing happens. How does it work?

[image: save charts button image]

This is my chart config

```
this.trendChart.update({
      series: {
          showInNavigator: true,
          dataGrouping: {
            approximation: "average"
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        id: 'series1',
      }],
      chart: {
        spacingRight: 35
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
              x: 0
            }
          }
      },
      stockTools: {
        gui: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }, 
    });
```

Any config change I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button save a chart in localStorage under `highcharts-chart` key. You can for example use it to keep some drawn annotations after refresing a browser.

The following items are stored:

- annotations
- indicators (with yAxes)
- flags

You can get the options in the following way:

---

```
const savedOptions = localStorage.getItem(['highcharts-chart']);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u6Lte04d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.merge%3CT%3E

Comment: can you please help in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68036756/15500072)

Comment: in this example not all indicators are being restored (e.g. pivotpoints, linearRegression). How to restore those after save? Is it also possible to save currently selected RangeSelector?

Comment: Hi @TomStack, That's correct, there is a feature request related to saving indicators: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17742 About range selector, yes - it is possible, but could you create a separate SO question for that?

Comment: Separate question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057762/highcharts-save-chart-button-of-stock-tool-chart-does-not-save-currently-selec