# To set Xaxis value to start from "00:00" in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to set Xaxis value to start from midnight i.e 00:00 on selecting any range selector button in highcharts i.e 1D/1W/3M/6M/ALL. The leftmost point of xaxis should start from last one month/week/.. date plus 00:00 time for any button but by default it shows last one month/week/.. date plus time which starts from current time i.e 18:30 (for example).

```
series: [
      {
        'name': '', 'data': [[]], 'type': 'line',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(this.curDate.getUTCFullYear(), this.curDate.getUTCMonth(), this.curDate.getUTCDate()),
      }
    ],
```

Comment: @ppotaczek can you please help?

Comment: Hi @Shawn, You can change `setExtremes` behaviour. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/azgcbfyn/ Do you want to have selected area related with current date, not with data on your chart?

Comment: @ppotaczek I want to show data from midnight(00:00) from every range selector button.

Comment: It should work fine in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1gmsvuh/