# highcharts - save chart button of stock tool chart does not save currently selected RangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Can functionality described here: [save chart button of stock tool chart not working in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67311156/save-chart-button-of-stock-tool-chart-not-working-in-highcharts) save also currently selected RangeSelector?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be to overwrite the default `saveChart` button functionality. In the below example saving all indicators and x-axis extremes should work correctly.

```
  const savedOptions = localStorage.getItem(['highcharts-chart']);
  const baseOptions = {...};

  H.stockChart('container', H.merge({
    navigation: {
      bindings: {
        saveChart: {
          init: function(button) {
            var navigation = this,
              chart = navigation.chart,
              annotations = [],
              series = [],
              xAxis = [],
              yAxis = [];

            annotations = chart.annotations.map(annotation => annotation.userOptions);

            chart.series.forEach(s => {
              if (!s.options.isInternal) {
                series.push(s.userOptions);
              }
            });
            chart.yAxis.forEach(axis => {
              if (axis.userOptions.className !== 'highcharts-navigator-yaxis') {
                yAxis.push(axis.userOptions);
              }
            });
            chart.xAxis.forEach((axis, index) => {
              if (!axis.options.isInternal) {
                xAxis.push(axis.userOptions);
                xAxis[index].min = axis.userMin;
                xAxis[index].max = axis.userMax;
              }
            });

            H.win.localStorage.setItem('highcharts-chart', JSON.stringify({
              series,
              annotations,
              yAxis,
              xAxis
            }));
            H.fireEvent(this, 'deselectButton', {
              button
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, savedOptions ? JSON.parse(savedOptions) : baseOptions));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r92b475e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings.saveChart

Comment: Thanks for this sample, but shouldn't it work out of the box without a need of overwrite the default saveChart button functionality?

Comment: Hi @TomStack, Here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Stock/StockTools/StockToolsBindings.ts#L1945 you can check how the default saveChart button functionality works. It just stores annotations, indicators and flags in localStorage under `highcharts-chart` key. You can create a feature request on Highcharts github if you think this should work differently.