# Having trouble reading property of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble accessing a property of an object I store in an array.

I store the properties like so:

```
let lights = [];

let newlightinfo = {
  active: true, // default value
  directional: false, // default value
  x: 0, // default value
  y: 1, // default value
  z: 0, // default value
  ia: vec3(75, 75, 75), // default value
  id: vec3(175, 175, 175), // default value
  is: vec3(RGB, RGB, RGB) // default value
}

let addlightbutton = {
    add: function() {
      if (lights.length <= MAX_LIGHTS) {
        let lightinfo = {
          active: newlightinfo.active,
          directional: newlightinfo.directional,
          x: newlightinfo.x,
          y: newlightinfo.y,
          z: newlightinfo.z,
          ia: newlightinfo.ia,
          id: newlightinfo.id,
          is: newlightinfo.is
        }
        lights.push(lightinfo);
      }
    }
```

I also tried to simply do  `let lightinfo = newlightinfo`, but it also didn't work, which makes sense.

I'm trying to do:

```
function lightInfo()
    { 
        if(lights.length > 0) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(lights[0]));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(lights[0].x));
            // Light information
            for(let i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++) {
                let x = lights[i].x; // error line
...
```

But I'm getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x').

I can't understand why since when printing out `lights[0]` and `lights[0].x` right before accessing my array everything seems right.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I'm using dat.gui to make the button functional in a browser interface, I don't think I can use that in a snippet too.

Comment: We don't need that, we just need you to post enough so we can see how you're calling the `add()` function and where you're trying to read the property after doing that.

Comment: If you call `add()` asynchronously, make sure you don't try to read the array before that completes.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to make my snippet work, sorry.

Comment: Then we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify that to `let lightinfo = {...newlightinfo};`

Answer (score 0):

this error only happens if array at 0 index is null, so if you add it in some way then use it, I guess maybe adding happens after accessing lights[0] so it's better to check if adding some how take longer than you think because of javascript nature

Comment: I do console.logs right before trying to access the x as shown here https://ibb.co/19YBQ5L

Comment: @Kob See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277332/javascript-console-log-reporting-object-properties-incorrectly

Comment: Change to `console.log(JSON.stringify(lights[0]))` and you'll see a difference.

Comment: @Barmar no change in the output, everyhting seems the same as the above image

Comment: show your whole code