# Why does this 2d array create unexpected results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, benchmarking

In the following code, I would expect a 2-dimensional array to be produced, pre-populated with zeros. The problem I am getting is that `x[0][3] = 2` seems to be happening too quickly, so by the time of the console log inside the function, the array has a changed value already. I can't seem to remedy this, even with timeouts. What's going on?

```
function test(size) {
    var row = [];
    var return_me = [];
    for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { row.push(0); }
    for (var j=0; j < size; j++) { return_me.push(row.slice()); }
    console.log("1:");
    console.log(return_me);
    return return_me;
}

var x = null;
console.log("0:");
console.log(x);
x = test(5);
console.log("2:");
console.log(x);
x[0][3] = 2;
console.log("3:");
console.log(x);
```

The unexpected result comes at the "1:" in the output, where I get:

```
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 2
4: 0
```

Comment: Is there an actual _error_ involved or does the log just look unexpected?

Comment: what are the log outcomes that you find unexpected?

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading: there is no error. I am updating the question with more specifics to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Array is an object, you will see the actual (latest) value of that as **`console.log()` shows a reference to the object** and by the time you are opening it, the value has changed. 
 
The option is to use `console.dir()` to print that current state of the object (although `console.dir()` does NOT work on chrome). 
 
If you want to get the real value in chrome, print that one value, not whole object. 
You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state) for expanded explanation and more info.

Comment: I was hoping it was something like that (not my function itself). Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I think everyone coding JS stumbles upon this thing sooner or later. :D