# angular 2 service injection issue

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, composition

**My project structure:**

[image]

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
import { Todo } from './components/shared/todo.model'
import { todos } from "./components/shared/todo.data"
import {TodoService} from "./components/shared/todoService"
import {TodoService} from "./components/shared/todoService";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    providers: [TodoService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title:string = "Angular 2Do";
}
```

**todo-form.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
import {Todo} from "../shared/todo.model";
import {TodoService} from "../shared/todoService"

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "todo-form",
    templateUrl: "todo-form.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["todo-form.component.css"],
})
export class TodoForm {
    ...
    constructor(private todoService:TodoService) {
        console.log(this.todoService);
        this.todoService.order = 2;
        console.log( this.todoService);
    }

}
```

**todo-list.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core"

import { ITodo } from "../shared/todo.model"
import { TodoService } from "../shared/todoService"

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "todo-list",
    templateUrl: "todo-list.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["todo-list.component.css"],
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
    todos:ITodo[];

    ...

    constructor(private todoService:TodoService) {
        ...
        console.log(this.todoService);
        this.todoService.order=1;
        console.log(this.todoService);

    }
   ...

}
```

`app` is the parent of the `list` and `form` components

Whaen I start application I see in console:

[image]

but if expand all I see:

[image]

Which result actual and why in second view I see `1` and in another `2`.

Comment: Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/w4wz302s/. You mutate property and console.log() prints a reference to the object, and by the time you pop it open, it's changed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console.log '+' button can only show you the current state of the object, not the object at the snapshot in time of when it was called.

See [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync) for a more in depth explanation.

So order: 1, is the final state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

never use providers( `providers: [TodoService]`  ) in component
as

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
import { Todo } from './components/shared/todo.model'
import { todos } from "./components/shared/todo.data"
import {TodoService} from "./components/shared/todoService"
import {TodoService} from "./components/shared/todoService";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent {
    title:string = "Angular 2Do";
}
```

it makes new instance when component initialise so put `providers` in module only ie. `NgModule`