# How to use 'this' in constructor execution order in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

After struggling with accessing `@ViewChild` in constructor I've come to an observation I do not understand. It had quite important consequences in my app.

Simplified `app.component.ts` code to demonstrate the point:

```ts
export class MyApp {
myProp: string;

constructor() {
    console.log( this ); //line A
    console.log( this.myProp ); //line B 
    this.myProp = 'my string'; //line C
}
```

Question is: why does `line A` output the whole app object WITH `myProp` set to `'my string'` while `line B` shows `myProp` as `undefined`?

In line A `this` should have `myProp` as `undefined` as well since it is only set in `line C`.

It is all against code order..

Comment: There is nothing to do with angular2 here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state

Comment: Yes, I supposed it was more of the way javascript in general is executed but could not find any clear answer. Many thanks, exactly what I stumbled on!

Comment: How is that related to `@ViewChild()`?

Comment: My initial problem was trying to load a page into 'nav' in the constructor. First I referenced it like so: @ViewChild( 'mainNav' ) nav: Nav; In the constructor 'this.nav' was undefined however 'this' had 'nav' property set properly (in console.log()). I solved the problem with ngOnInit hook (realized the view was not ready in the constructor stage) but discovered the 'issue' with the order in question. Sorry if the opening about @ViewChild was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is order:

```
constructor() {
    console.log( this ); //line A
    this.myProp = 'my string'; //line B
    console.log( this.myProp ); //line C 
}
```