# Why isnt "this" work with console.log as an argument?

Tags: javascript, this

I assumed that .call should //change the context of this in the log method to obj, but it doesnt seem to be //doing that, it seems to refer to the window object as if I used this side a function

```
let obj={
    a: "this should work right?"
}

console.log.call(obj,this.a);//returns undefined
```

Comment: Arguments to a function are evaluated before calling the function, so the context isn't set to the `obj` at that point.

Comment: because `this` in `this.a` isn't changed by using .call - Barmar said it better :p

Comment: *this* is a property of an execution context, it shouldn't be referred to as "context".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log object at current state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/console-log-object-at-current-state)

Comment: @Z.Bagley—I don't think that's a duplicate. The OP has missed that `this.a` is evaluated before it's passed to *console.log*, so whatever *this* refers to in the method is irrelevant to the result of the overall statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not in a function scope, instead you should test this way:

```
let obj={
    a: "this should work right?"
};

let myFunc = function() { // u define a function scope here
    return this.a;
};

console.log(myFunc.call(obj));
// console.log.call(obj,this.a);
```