# JSX, React-redux - differently accessing object key value - responses differ

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am using react-redux and am trying to access an object's key value. Initially "**isBookmarked**" value is **false** and after *onClick* using actions and then reducers it has been set to **true**.

Finally I am trying to console log the value as so:

```
{console.log("data[19].isBookmarked", data[19].isBookmarked)}
{console.log("data[19]", data[19])}
```

Responses differ although this is the same object:

[see console.log response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOdEU.png)

These lines are sequential - they have nothing else between them and they execute one after the other.

I also tried *console.log*'ing via accessing key value as so - `data[19]["isBookmarked"]`, but same response.

Here is the object i'm talking about as

```
{
      "id": 1373,
      "isBookmarked": true,
      "category": {
        "id": 5457
      },
      "owner": {
        "id": 63
      },
      "publishDate": "2017-07-25T12:11:13+03:00",
      "views": 0,
      "texts": [
        {
          "id": 1371,
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          "languageCode": "en"
        }
      ],
      "files": []
}
```

Comment: first you're logging out the objects' property named "isBookmarked" and then you're logging out the whole object.. so what exactly is your question here?

Comment: @VF_ when i log out the whole object, the value is **true**, but when i log out the key value - it is **false**

Comment: this has nothing to do with react.

Comment: when you're logging data[19].isBookmarked, you have the value at this given time, when you're logging the whole object, and it changed afterward, you have the value that will change because you're logging the reference. I'm pretty sure you're logging before mutating your object. 
And as @abdul said, it's a simple javascript problem

Comment: Look at this post please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-change-the-default-behavior-of-console-log-in-safari

Comment: @Nevosis this is not true - these both logs are two concurrent lines of code and nothing is being mutated at that time: 
http://imgur.com/I4upHY9

Comment: it is mutated right after, and in the second case you're logging the reference. Look at the little "i" in your chrome console and you'll get what I say.