# Angular 2 @ViewChild("graphCanvas") graphCanvas: ElementRef is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am facing a quite strange behaviour of my DOM element, by building an application with angular 2.

I am using a canvas element to draw a graph inside of it and I am selecting the element by using @ViewChild. Somehow angular says that it can not further execute any methods because of undefined.

So I logged out exactly before the error occurs.

`console.log(this);
console.log(this.graphCanvas);`

The result:
[image]

Hope you get what I mean. this contains the graphCanvas element but if I try accessing it I got a undefined.

**EDIT:**
I am using a map to draw circles on this map (data viz project). The problem only occurs when I start the application and only if I use the search the first time. Both methods, search and click on circle, head to the same methods.

**Click on Circle - working:**
[image]

```
cityCircle.addListener('click', function (e) {
 localThis.currentCity = cityCircle.data_obj;
    localThis.cityClicked = true
    localThis.zone.run(() => {});
    cityCircle.setOptions({
        fillColor: '#d7490b',
        strokeColor: '#026384'
    });
    if (localThis.currentCircleInMap) {
        localThis.currentCircleInMap.setOptions({
            fillColor: '#026384',
            strokeColor: '#026384'
        });
    }
    localThis.currentCircleInMap = cityCircle;

    localThis.map.setCenter({
        lat: localThis.currentCity.geo_data.lat,
        lng: localThis.currentCity.geo_data.lng
    });
    localThis.map.setZoom(10);
    localThis.setGraphView(localThis.currentCity.data_by_year);
});
```

**Search - not working:**
[image]

```
autoCompleteClicked(event): void {    
    try {
      var cityClickedKey = event.getAttribute('data-city');
    } catch (error) {
      var cityClickedKey = event.value;
    }

    this.globalData.migration_data.forEach(element => {     
      if (element.city.includes(cityClickedKey)) {        
        this.currentCity = element;
        this.map.setCenter({
          lat: this.currentCity.geo_data.lat,
          lng: this.currentCity.geo_data.lng
        });
        this.map.setZoom(10);
        this.highlightClickedCircle()
        this.cityClicked = true;
      }
    });
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("search")).value = this.currentCity.city;
    this.autoCompleteAvailable = false;
    this.setGraphView(this.currentCity.data_by_year);}
```

In the setGraphView method the element child is not set.

Comment: The message by itself is not enough to understand what's going on. Could you add some relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` can only show you the current state of the object, not the object of the snapshot at the time of when it was called.

It prints a reference to the object, and by the time you see it in web devtool, it's changed.

So I suspect you are trying to get Viewchild at the time when it is not filled.

See also:

- [How can I make console.log show the current state of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-change-the-default-behavior-of-console-log-in-safari)
- [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)