# How to refer the field from this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have a object with printout from a console.log() command:

```
console.log("event in validation ", this.event_info);
```

Here is the printout:

```
event in validation  {"start_datetime":"Sun Jul 14 2019 18:20:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)","finish_datetime":"Mon Jul 15 2019 18:20:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"}
```

There are 2 fields in `this.event_info`: `start_datetime` and `finish_datetime`. I need to refer the value of `finish_datetime` and did the following:

```
this.event_info["finish_datetime"];
```

and

```
let sd = "finish_datetime";
this.event_info[sd];
```

But there are nothing retrieved (undefined or nothing). Then I tried to print out the keys of the object:

```
 Object.keys(this.event_info);
```

And printout is:

```
 [ '0',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  .
  .
  .
  99
```

Then I tried these:

```
 this.event_info["1"];
```

and:

```
this.event_info[1];
```

It is nothing printed out again. What is the right way here to refer the value of `finish_datetime`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't overwrite the variable? You should show us the entire code to see where the problem comes from

Comment: `this.event_info` is a JSON string. You want `JSON.parse(this.event_info).finish_datetime`

Comment: @Phil I bet your comment is right, don't you want to write an answer with that info? If this is not a duplicate it is a good question.

Comment: @RaulSauco I'd say it classifies as a _typo_ / no longer a problem. A modicum of debugging (like with a debugger) would reveal the data type of OP's variable. The only real take-away from this is that `console.log()` is **not** a debugging tool.

Comment: **Object.keys(obj)** returns the keys of your object. **Object.values(obj)** returns the values and **Object.entries(obj)** returns an array of arrays ([key, value]) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries. So it's not surprising that for **Object.keys(obj)** you get an array of numbers.

Comment: @Phil fair enough

Comment: @RaulSauco changed my mind and added a community-wiki answer below. Feel free to help improve it, especially the list of debugging tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Long Answer

`console.log()` is a terrible debugging tool. It does not show data types and what it shows is [not always a correct representation of the state of your application at the time you call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-change-the-default-behavior-of-console-log-in-safari).

You should instead use your browser's actual debugger or one connected via your editor / IDE.

- Chrome - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/
- Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger
- Visual Studio Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

#### Short Answer

Your variable is a JSON string, not an object. You want

```js
JSON.parse(this.event_info).finish_datetime
```

Comment: Save my day and thank you! I was confused by https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp and treated it as JSON object instead of JSON string.