# javascript Add data to object type key undefined

Tags: javascript, object

in javascript after i add some data in to object type

key undefined

here is my code

```js
let ErrName = {};

formSchema.validate(values, { abortEarly: false }).catch(function (err) {
  err.inner.forEach((e) => {
    ErrName[e.path] = e.message;
  });
  return ErrName;
});
    
console.log(ErrName);
```

this is my result in console

```
{}
email: "Email is required"
password: "Password is required"
[[Prototype]]: Object

   console.log(ErrName.email);

undefined
```

Comment: Don't use the console for debugging, [it does not always represent the truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-make-console-log-show-the-current-state-of-an-object)

Comment: even  in return <h1>{ErrName.email}</h1> does not show anything