# Why is my array coming up as undefined when I try to access the individual elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load two user-defined csv files and programmatically compare them (essentially trying to find errors in the files and report those errors to the user). I'm uploading the first and am running into a problem. When I display the entire array `console.log(results);` it shows me the entire array in the console. However if I try to get the first row `console.log(results[0]);` I simply see 'undefined' in the console. I also have the same issue when I call `console.log(deviceData);` in a later snippet of code (works for the entire array but the second I try to access an element I get an `undefined`). What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    var deviceData = new Array();
    const uploadConfirm = document.getElementById('uploadConfirm').addEventListener('click', () => {
        Papa.parse(document.getElementById('deviceFile').files[0],
        {
            download: true,
            header: false,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function(results){
                console.log(results[0]);
                deviceData = results;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You don't have `console.log(results);` anywhere in your code. Was it in the exact same spot as where `console.log(results[0]);` is?

Comment: What is `Papa` ? This can be caused by how the browser's console works. It can be that when `console.log(results[0])` is executed, `results` is empty, and then, when it is populated, the browser's console updates and it shows its latest content.

Comment: I don't understand what API `Papa.parse` refers to, BUT you should test to see if the results response is parsed or what type of format it is. Try `console.log(typeof results)`

Comment: My apologies, yes, `console.log(results[0])` is where I am adding and removing the `[0]`. `console.log(results)` works, `console.log(results[0])` does not.

I am using Papa Parse. I reference it in my code earlier on with this:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `console.log(typeof results)` shows `object` in the console

Comment: The console updates references live, what you are seeing for `console.log(results)` is the updated value once your parser completes its **asynchronous** action. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389069/283366) for more on why the console is **not** a good debugging tool

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#results) of the library that you're using, the actual data is under `results.data`, try `console.log(results.data[0])`, that should give you the expected output.

Comment: Sure enough, `console.log(results.data[0])` worked for that part of the code, thanks Titus. For the second part, trying to assign an object to an array was the issue (thank you for pointing me in the right direction Kinglish). I changed the assignment to `deviceData = Object.values(results);` and now I can access `deviceData` properly.

Comment: It looks like my question shows "[duplicate]" and includes a link to a question claimed to be related, however I wanted to point out the linked question did not solve my problems. My problems were solved by accessing the correct place for the data and assigning the right type of data (see above comment).