# Can't use data in js object when displaying old data on a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, fetch-api, json-server

I have a update button that lets someone update information through a form in `Update.js`

I'm trying to get the old data stored in my db.json file through json-server and show them by default on the input fields in the Update form in `Update.js`

Fetching data part is done through a custom hook called `useFetch`.

But all I get is a blank page and the object I get from `useFetch` is null for some reason (I have included the error I got at bottom)

I've read similar questions here but none seems have the exact problem I'm facing.

**Update.js**

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import { useState } from "react";

const Update = () => {
    
    const {id} = useParams();
    
    const {data: old, isLoading, error} =  useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`)

    // console.log(old.title);
    // line 14
    const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(old.title);
    const [newAuthor, setNewAuthor] = useState('');
    const [newBody, setNewBody] = useState('');

    // const handleUpdate = () => {
    //     fetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`,{
    //     method: 'PUT',
    //     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    //     body:  JSON.stringify()
    // })
    // }

    return (     
        <div className="update-article">
            {/* <p>{old.title}</p> */}
            <form action="">
                <label htmlFor="">Blog Title</label>
                <input type="text" 
                    value={newTitle} 
                    onChange={(e) => setNewTitle(e.target.value)} 
                />
            </form>
        </div>       
     );
}
 
export default Update;
```

I have used `useFetch` to get data in another component and it works without issues there.

**UseFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
        // vars for blog items in an array
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);

        //loader
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    
        //error storing
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url) 
                .then((response) => {
                    //check for fetch failure
                    if(!response.ok){
                        console.log("Server error");
                        throw Error("Could not fetch data for that resource");
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    setData(data);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setError(null);        
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setError(error.message);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                })         
        return () => console.log("Cleanup running...");
    }, [url]);


    return {data, isLoading, error}
}

export default useFetch;
```

When I try to run this, I get a blank page and in the browser console and I get `Uncaught TypeError: old is null` for line 14 in `Update.js` [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN34O.jpg)

Line 14 is: `const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(old.title);`

The blank page goes away and shows the input text box if I remove the `old.title` in line 14 (setting the initial value of `newTitle` to empty string or null)

And if I remove the `old.title` as initial value and type `console.log(old.title)`. It shows the correct data in the console. So old is not null (?)

What I have tried:

1. Tried to assign everything in the `old` object to temporary variables and assign them to the value field in imput box.
2. Using `defaultValue` instead of `value` in input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that on the first render **old** will be null as the api call is still pending. Now after the api call is fulfilled, you sure will receive something and so **old** is no more null.

Here you are accessing title on first render as well as subsequent renders (old.title). So on first render you get the error `Uncaught TypeError: old is null`. You cann't access anything on null or undefined object.

Now if we talk about your console log, the reason it's printing the actual value is if you are printing object x times in console, it will only give you the last updated value all the x times. [Here is a wonderful answer you can take a look at.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-make-console-log-show-the-current-state-of-an-object)

Anyways in order to solve the problem there are 2 ways.

1. Add `?` before accessing title from old so it will become `old?.title` for line 14 in Update.js. This is the easiest method.
2. Add a `useEffect` hook to update `newTitle` state whenever there is a change in `old` and there also you need a check for null or undefined. Here is the updated code for `Update.js`.

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
   import useFetch from './useFetch';
   import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

   const Update = () => {
     const { id } = useParams();

     const {
       data: old,
       isLoading,
       error,
     } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`);

     // console.log(old.title);
     // line 14
     const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(null);
     const [newAuthor, setNewAuthor] = useState('');
     const [newBody, setNewBody] = useState('');

     // const handleUpdate = () => {
     //     fetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`,{
     //     method: 'PUT',
     //     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     //     body:  JSON.stringify()
     // })
     // }

     useEffect(() => {
       if (old) {
         setNewTitle(old.title);
       }
     }, [old]);

     return (
       <div className="update-article">
         {/* <p>{old.title}</p> */}
         <form action="">
           <label htmlFor="">Blog Title</label>
           <input
             type="text"
             value={newTitle}
             onChange={(e) => setNewTitle(e.target.value)}
           />
         </form>
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Update;
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. The 2nd method worked. Adding the `?` did make the blank page go away but didn't display the old values.