# Empty object passing in axios - Vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am sending an object from `this.productDetails` as part of an `axios.post()` request. Upon inspecting the payload in the browser's network tab, I observe that the object is devoid of any data.

**Here's the Axios call**:

```
        async addProduct(){
            console.log('product_details', this.productDetails)
            const apiResponse = await axios.post('add_product',{
                productDetails : this.productDetails
            })

            const response = apiResponse.data
        },
```

I have consoled it by: `console.log('product_details', this.productDetails)` and it does has the actual object: [image: console.log of the object I am passing]

**This is my Laravel route:**

```
    Route::post('add_product',[PackageSubscriptionController::class, 'addProduct']);
```

**Here's the Network**:
[image]

Comment: `console.log` of objects can be deceptive - what happens if you `console.log('product_details', JSON.stringify(this.productDetails))`

Comment: `this.productDetails` is actaully an array, sorry for that. This is my declaration of it. `productDetails: []`

Comment: which is still an object so my point still stands

Comment: sort of yeah, but the `console.log('product_details', JSON.stringify(this.productDetails))` returns `product_details []`.

Comment: so, it's an empty array - not sure why "sort of" ... an Array is still an Object, as `typeof []` will show you

Comment: Objects are passed by reference in JS, which is the case. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389069/how-can-i-make-console-log-show-the-current-state-of-an-object?

Comment: @EstusFlask  Yes, I passed the object's current state as arg to the addProduct(), and to my surprise, it is an empty array. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the state of the object. I had initiated `this.productDetails` as an empty array in a parent component and then passed it on to a child component where that data would get loaded into the `this.productDetails`, and in the `axios.post` the initial state of the object which was an empty array was getting passed. I still have not figured it out how to pass the desired state of the object and I would love to know more about the state. So any references to learn more about states is appreciated.

**Here's what I changed in the `axios.post` and it worked for me.** I know it's a shortcut but I have a deadline to meet so I will go with it for now.

```
        async addProduct(){
            const data          = this.productDetails
            const apiResponse   = await axios.post('add_product',{
                                        name            : data.name,
                                        description     : data.description,
                                        price           : data.price,
                                        livemode        : data.livemode,
                                        active          : data.active,
                                    })
            const response      = apiResponse.data
        },
```