how to handle seperate FormData in the replicated form?
I am trying to creating a dashboard with panels of different sizes and re-arrange able according to the users will also the panel have different formData inside the same panel Form.

Expected : to get the formData from the first panelform and i have stored it in a hidden input element inside the first formData and likewise for n number of panel i want to achieve this, then for saving the panels i want to iterate over the each panels and get the formData that is stored in each panels.
Dashboard 1

panel 1 {"type":"1","chartType":"bar","panellogsource":"19","fieldSelected":["dst_as","dst_mask"],"timeWindow":"Last 15 Minutes"}
panel 2 {"type":"2","aggregateType":"count","panellogsource":"19","fieldSelected":["dst_port","dst_tos"],"timeWindow":"Last 15 Minutes"}

Actual : i am able to set the data for the first panel but after populating the second panel the form is retrieving the previous(first) panel data. i want to separate the panels formData for each panel.
Dashboard 1

panel 1 {"type":"1","chartType":"bar","panellogsource":"19","fieldSelected":["dst_as","dst_mask"],"timeWindow":"Last 15 Minutes"}
panel 2 {"type":"1","chartType":"bar","panellogsource":"19","fieldSelected":["dst_as","dst_mask"],"timeWindow":"Last 15 Minutes"}  (same content for the second panel)

<div class="panel-container col-lg-${layoutSize}">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="panel card-body ibox">
      <div class="panel-heading card-title ibox-title">
        <h5>Drag&amp;Drop ${layoutSize}</h5>
        <div class="ibox-tools d-flex">
          <a class="collapse-link" onclick="return collapseIbox(event, this);">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown options ms-auto">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="editPanel()" class="dropdown-item"
                  >Edit Content</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                  Size:
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-l btn-primary"
                    onclick="changeSize(this, 'lg');"
                    title="Full Row"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o fs-6"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-m btn-primary"
                    onclick="changeSize(this, 'md');"
                    title="2 Column Row"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o fs-5"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-s btn-primary"
                    onclick="changeSize(this, 'sm');"
                    title="3 Column Row "
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o fs-4"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
                    onclick="changeSize(this, 'xs');"
                    title="4 Column Row"
                  >
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o fs-3"></i>
                  </button>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a class="close-link" onclick="return closeIbox(event, this);">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content">
        <!-- add new content to the panel -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light ms-2" onclick="editPanel()">
          Edit Panel
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Panel Loading Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="panelCreateModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Panel Data</h5>
        <button
          id="icon-modal-close"
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <i class="bx bx-x text-white font"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%@ include file="../dashboard/panel_create.jsp"%>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

panel_create.jsp
<div class="panel">
    <form class="row g-3" id="PanelCreationForm" onsubmit="return false;">
        <!-- TYPE-> CHART,AGGREGATION -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="type" class="form-label">Type<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" required
                onchange="toggleType(this.value)">
                <option value="select" selected disabled>Select</option>
                <option value="1" ${panel ne null and panel.type eq '1' ? 'selected' : ''}>Chart</option>
                <option value="2" ${panel ne null and panel.type eq '2' ? 'selected' : ''}>Aggregation</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- CHART OPTION / AGGREGATE OPTION -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="type" class="form-label">Chart / Aggregate<span style="color: red;">*</span></label><select name="chartType" id="chartType"
                class="form-control" required>
                <option value="select" selected disabled>Select Chart</option>
                <c:forEach var="option" items="${chartOptions}">
                    <option value="${option.value}" <c:if test="${option.value == panel.typeData}">selected</c:if>>${option.displayText}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> <select name="aggregateType" id="aggregateType" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="select" selected disabled>Select Aggregate</option>
                <c:forEach var="option" items="${aggregateOptions}">
                    <option value="${option.value}" <c:if test="${option.value == panel.typeData}">selected</c:if>>${option.displayText}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- LogSource -->
            <label for="logsource" class="form-label">Log Source<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <select name="panellogsource" id="panellogsource"
                class="form-control" required>
                <option value="select" selected disabled>Select</option>
                <c:forEach var="logSource" items="${LogSource.sources()}">
                    <option value="${logSource.logId}" <c:if test="${logSource.logId eq panel.logSource}">selected</c:if>>${logSource.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- FIELD -->
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <!-- Field Multi Select -->
            <label class="form-label">Field<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div id="fieldSelectDiv">
                <select multiple name="fieldSelected" class="form-control form-control-cust" id="fieldSelect" required>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- Time Window -->
            <button type="button" style="margin-left: 4px" data-popover-content="#pop-time-window-content" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-light btn-icon-custom time-window-pop" id="wTimeWindowCalendar" title="Time Window">
                <i class="bx bx-calendar font-20"></i>
            </button>
            <input style="min-width: 300px !important; max-width: 300px !important;" type="text" name="timeWindow" id="timeWindow"
                class="form-control form-control-cust timeWindowInput" placeholder="Time Window" data-time-window="last-1-year"
                value="${panel ne null ? panel.timeWindow: ''}" readonly>
            <!-- Time Window End -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Panel Data type="hidden"  -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="panelData" value=" ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="padding-top: 25px; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <c:if test="${page eq 'new'}">
                <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:addPanelData()" class="btn btn-light px-5" id="btnSubmit">Add</button>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${page eq 'edit'}">
                <button type="submit" onclick="javascript:updatePanelData()" class="btn btn-light px-5" id="btnSubmit">Update</button>
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

js function to add the formData to each panel

function addPanelData() {
    console.log("addPanelData");
    // Iterate over each panel container
    $('.panel').each(function(index) {
        var formDataObject = {};
        // Serialize the form data for the current panel
        var formData = $(this).find('form').serializeArray();
        console.log("formData: ", formData);
        $.each(formData, function(i, field) {
            if(field.name==='fieldSelected'){
                if(!formDataObject[field.name]){
                    formDataObject[field.name]=[];  
                }
                formDataObject[field.name].push(field.value);
            }else{
                formDataObject[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        });

        console.log(`Form Data for Panel ${index}:`, formDataObject);

        // Convert formDataObject to JSON string and store it in the hidden input field panelData
        $(this).find('input[id="panelData"]').val(JSON.stringify(formDataObject));
        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
    });
}


function editPanel(){
    $('#panelCreateModal').modal('show');
    var form = $(this).find('form')[0];
    if (form) {
        form.reset(); // Reset only if the form exists
    } else {
        console.log('Form not found in this panel.');
    }
    
    let dashboardId = sessionStorage.getItem("dashboardId");
    console.log("editPanel :",dashboardId);
    var panelData = $("#panelData").val(); 
    console.log("Retrieved panelData:", panelData);
    //get the panelData from the closest element in the form for each panel
    var button=$('#btnSubmit');
    var closestelement = button.closest('.col-md-12');
    console.log("closestelement :",closestelement);
    $("#panelData").val(panelData);
    var panelDataInput = closestelement.find('#panelData');
    console.log(panelDataInput);
    console.log(panelDataInput.val());
   }

Edit Panel - editPanel() retrieves data back from the hidden field its showing

"but after populating the second panel the form is retrieving the previous(first) panel data" - is the wrong data actually getting stored into the hidden input field - or is it perhaps just your console.log(\Form Data for Panel ${index}:`, formDataObject); that appears to show the same data for every panel? (console.logis "live" in that regard, it always shows the _current_ state of an object when you inspect it in the console, not the state of the object at the timeconsole.log` was executed - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389069/1427878)

code missing updated with the editPanel() which i use to retrieve the specific values of the form this code shows the no form found and displays the old data ie. data of first paneldata

Looks like you are using duplicate IDs, which you of course MUST NOT do. var panelData = $("#panelData").val(); will only ever get you the value of the first field in the document with that ID. Setting the value using $(this).find('input[id="panelData"]') might have worked, because you are using an attribute selector there. But a duplicate ID is an error, nevertheless. You will either need to modify the IDs when you are cloning elements(?), or use classes instead to begin with.
