# Why are my objects showing up as "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bubble sort an array of records by age but all I get is:

> [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]

How can I get it to display the values of the record?

```
students = [
    {name: "timothy", age: "9"},
    {name: "claire",  age: "12"},
    {name: "michael", age: "20"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < students.length; j++) {
        if (Number(students[i].age) > Number(students[j].age)) {
            tempValue = students[j].age;
            students[j].age = students[i].age;
            students[i].age = tempValue;
        }
    }
}

alert(students);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i print a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object)

Comment: btw, be careful about using undeclared variables like "students" and "tempValue". By default they can be global and that is often not what you want.

Answer (score 11):

By default, all objects in JavaScript turn to `"[object Object]"` when they are converted to a string (as is the case with `alert()`).

You can try to:

- Use console.log or a debugger to inspect the array (instead of using alert())

  ```
  console.log(students);
  //Open your browser's developer tools to see the console.
  //Try F12, ctrl+shift+J or ctrl+shift+I as shortcuts
  ```
- Use the `JSON.stringify` function to serialize the objects.

  ```
  JSON.stringify({a:1});
  //yields '{"a":1}'
  ```
- Give your objects a custom toString method

  ```
  var x = {
      a : 17,
      toString: function(){
          return 'I have a ' + this.a;
      }
  };
  alert(x); //gives "I have a 17"
  ```

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+I` in Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

In supported browsers you could alert or log a JSON string representation:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(students));
```