# JavaScript - how to print all values from an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get one object from this array and print all of its values into a div, Is it possible

```
function Car(company, name, price, details, image, alt){ 
        this.company = company;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.details = details;
        this.image = image;
        this.alt = alt;
    }

var carInformation = [new Car("Company: Ferrari", "Name: Marenello", "Price: $250,000", "Details: Fast. Very Fast.", "images/ferrari.jpg","image of ferrari"),
                          new Car("Company: Dodge", "Name: Viper", "Price: $100,000","Details: Great Acceleration","images/dodge.jpg", "image of viper"),
                          new Car("Company: Ford", "Name: Shelby", "Price: $80,000", "Details: Muscle Car", "images/mustang.jpg", "image of mustang"),
                          new Car("Company: Back To The Future", "Name: Delorean", "Price: $20,000", "Details: Travels through time","images/delorean.jpg", "image of delorean"),
                          new Car("Company: Lamborghini", "Name: Diablo", "Price: $250,000", "Details: Fastest","images/lambo.jpg","image of lamborghini"),
                          new Car("Company: Mercedes Benz", "Name: SLR", "Price: $180,000", "Details: Classy Vehicle.","images/benz.jpg","image of mercedes benz"),
                          new Car("Company: Chevrolet", "Name: Corvette", "Price: $70,000", "Details: Fiberglass body Light Vehicle.","images/vette.jpg","image of corvette"),
                          new Car("Company: Porsche", "Name: Carrera", "Price: $120,000", "Details: Great Handling.","images/porsche.jpg", "image of porsche"),
                          new Car("Company: Audi", "Name: R8", "Price: $110,000", "Details: Fast and Classy.", "images/audi.jpg","image of audi") ];

    for(i=0;i<carInformation.length;i++) {
    $('#container').append('<div class="product"><li><a href="#" ><img src="' + carInformation[i].image + '" alt="' + carInformation[i].alt +'" ></img></a></li><div class="description"><p class="carCompany">'+ carInformation[i].company +'</p><p class="carName">'+ carInformation[i].name +'</p><p class="carPrice">'+ carInformation[i].price +'</p><p class="carDetails">'+ carInformation[i].details +'</p></div></div>');
    $('#productPage').append('<div id="carInfo">' + carInformation[i] + '</div>');

        }
```

The '#container' line works. Is it possible to just print all the values without writing each property? Like I attempted in the '#productPage'?
 It returns object Object. why? When I write console.log(carInformation[0]); I am able to see all the values in the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object)

Comment: *"It returns object Object. why?"* Because this is the default string representation of an object. Since objects consist of multiple properties, you have to access those in order to get their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

carInformation[i] is an object. The best you could do is, add a protoype method to your car, such that it spills out all the properties and then it could be rendered in side the div.

```
function view(){
return "Company " + this.company + ",Name   " + this.Name + ", Price " + this.price ;
}


Car.prototype.view = view;

//and then use it inside div
 $('#productPage').append('<div id="carInfo">' + carInformation[i].view + '</div>');
```

You could control the how the information of car is displayed by rendering HTML rather than plain string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see the magic:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(carInformation[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some functions to write your variables into the divs. You can add these to the prototype for `Car`.

```
function Car(company, name, price, details, image, alt){ 
    this.company = company;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.details = details;
    this.image = image;
    this.alt = alt;
    }

Car.prototype.product = function() {
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+this.image +'"alt="'+this.alt+'"></img></a></li>';
    };

Car.prototype.description = function() {
    return '<p class="carCompany">'+this.company+'</p><p class="carName">'+this.name +'</p><p class="carPrice">'+ this.price +'</p><p class="carDetails">'+ this.details +'</p>';
    };
```

You can then call the functions on the objects to fill in your divs.

```
 for(i=0;i<carInformation.length;i++) {
    $('#container').append('<div class="product">'+carInformation[i].product()+'<div class="description">' + carInformation[i].description() + '</div></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

```
var car = new Car( ... );
var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
for(var key in car) {
  $ul.append("<li>" + car[key] + "</li>");
}
$('#container').append($ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all properties by iterating through object:
I suppose, you'll print your object also in other cases and i think, this is good solution for it - mini templating :)

```
Car.prototype.view = function( template, separator ) {
  var arr=[], template = template || "<%name%>: <%value%>",
  separator = separator || "\n";
  foreach( var i in this ) { 
    if( this.hasOwnProperty( i ) ){ 

        arr[arr.length] = template.replace("<%name%>",i).replace("<%value%>" , this[i]);
    }

  } 
  return arr.join(separator);
};


// that will be print list of names each property in car :)
console.log( "<ul>" + yourCar.view( "<li><%name%><li>") +"</ul>") ;
```

This is just a simple example that you can somehow extend for your purpose. ( getters for some properties eg. - image property, getter might return at once image tag :) )

I have not tested this, may be missing comma or something.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution than any of these would simply to do something like this:

```js
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(car)) {
     //code, key being the property name, and value being the value of said key
}
```