# Create/ creating the variable's dict dynamically and print

Tags: javascript

I want print the dict a in alert , (it is possible?) or print in the third's textarea (three) with `id=p`.
I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object) and I used

```
document.getElementById("p").value=JSON.stringify(a);;
    alert("myObject is " + a.toSource());
    console.log(a);
```

These not function.
The example is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example - print the dict</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id = 'button1' type = 'button' value = 'print the dict' onclick="updateHistory()"/>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var count ="?foo=1&oo=298529982";

function updateHistory()
{

 var a = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < document.formparam.elements.length; i++)
{

    var field = document.formparam.elements[i];
    a[field.name] = field.value;
}

document.getElementById("p").value=JSON.stringify(a);;
alert("myObject is " + a.toSource());
console.log(a);
}


</script>
<form method="GET" name="formparam" id="formparam" ><table><tr><td><textarea name="name" >john</textarea></td><td><textarea name="surname">jackold</textarea></td></tr></table></form>
<textarea id="p"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you meaning you want to change `console.log(a)` to `alert(a)`? If so, you should just start using a console instead.

Comment: no I want print the dict in one alert or in textarea,
I used the Firebug and I see this dict but I'm not sure

Comment: Dict?  Don't you mean javascript object?

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(a)); Now I print only []

Comment: `.toSource()` is not a standard function, but do you see the expected value inside the text area?

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani That's because the base type of `a` is an array and you're not adding items using `.push()`.

Comment: Yes.... but I wrong initialize the variable a 
var a ={};

Comment: But this question is for the dict with a=[] and ot a={}

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani, the way you are using the array [] in your code will no work. You need an object {}.

Comment: There are no dictionaries in javascript, as far as I am aware.  There are objects, and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `JSON.stringify()` on an array will iterate over the array like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    // process value of a[i]
}
```

But because you're adding properties to the object using `a[field.name]`, those are not added to the list of array items, unlike `a.push(value)`. As such, `JSON.stringify()` will print `[]`.

You should either:

1. Define `a` as an object, i.e. `var a = {};`
2. Iterate over the keys yourself:

   ```
   for (var k in a) {
       if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
           // process value of a[k]
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`var a = new Array();`

should be

`var a = {};` or `var a = new Object();`

There are no dictonnaries in JavaScript, however, you can use an object as a key/value store. To alert the `object` as JSON, you can just do `alert(JSON.stringify(a));`.