# JQuery failing to reorder an element in a list; how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my JQuery to select one of the navigation links—based on the page that I'm on—and then I want it to move it to the top of the list.

This is the HTML of my navigation bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul id=nav>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php">Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php"><icon>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the JQuery I'm using to try and reorder the list:

```
var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
var ul = $('nav').children('ul'),
    li = ul.children('li');
$(document).ready(function(){
    ul.prepend($('a[href*='+page+']').parent());
});
```

Needless to say, it isn't working.

By the way `alert(page);`

outputs the name of the file of the page that I'm on, ei: "**contact.php**", but `alert($('a[href*=page]').parent());`

just outputs "**[object Object]**"

. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should use console.log(obj) to print the object. You can also refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. The `ul` is `undefined`, you should select the element using `$('ul')` or `$('#nav')`.
2. You haven't closed the document ready handler. Missing `)`.
3. You don't concatenate the strings, ie  `$('a[href*='+page+']').parent()`

Also for debugging you should use the `console` object and `log()` the value, `alert` tries to the show the string representation of a value, it outputs `[object Object]` as `toString()` method of the above object returns this value. `console.log(anIdentifier).`

Update:

Note that you are selecting the elements before the DOM is ready, so when you are trying to select the element as the DOM is not ready, `ul` can be an empty collection. You should select the elements within the document ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('#nav'), li = ul.children('li');

    ul.prepend($('a[href*=page]').parent());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the debug! By the way, my actual code wasn't missing the `);` I just forgot to copy and paste that in. Though I was wondering if I could make my definition of `ul` more finite by doing this: `ul = $('nav').children('ul'),`

Comment: @LarryK Yes, you can and it's a good practice as you don't recreate the objects (_caching_), if the element has an ID, using ID selector is more efficient `$('#nav')`.

Comment: @wared Well, when I had posed the answer (_before the update_), the `ul` was `undefined`. The update invalidated the first and second items.

Comment: @undefined Okay, now my code looks like this: `var ul = $('nav').children('ul'),
 li = ul.children('li');
$(document).ready(function(){
 ul.prepend($('a[href*='+page+']').parent());
});` but it's still not working.

Comment: @undefined Wow thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the `li` with the given url then call the prepend

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
    $('#nav a[href="' + page + '"]').parent().prependTo('#nav');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/97zrD/)

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to change it to `$('ul')` to get the ul element
2. `$('a[href*=page]')` should be `$('a[href*="'+page+'"]')`

so it will look like:

```
var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').prepend($('a[href*="'+page+'"]').parent());
});
```

** For debugging, you may use `console.log()` and check in the browser console instead of using `alert()`, it can provide you more information.