# select box notice Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'DepCod' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

google chrome notice "Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'DepCod' of undefined"

Please fix my code and tell me why is my code does not work

```
$.ajax({
    url:base_url + 'c_category/departList',
    data:'',
    dataType: "text",
    cache:false,
    type:'post',
    success: function(dep){
    if(dep !== ''){    
    var re = $.parseJSON(dep);
    var counts = dep.length;               
    var i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<counts;i++){
    $.each(re ,function(index,value){
          $("#deps").append("<option value="+value[i].DepCod+">"+value[i].DepLocNam+</option>");
    //  alert(value[dep][0].DepCod);

    });
    }
    } else {
    $('.dep').html("no data"); 
    }
    },
    error:function(){
    $('.dep').html("error"); 
    }
    });
```

this is my controller

```
    function departList(){

    $query['dep'] = $this->m_category->getAllDepart();
    echo json_encode($query);
    }
```

and model

```
    function getAllDepart(){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('DEPMST');              
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query->result();            
    }
```

and bootstrap html

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dep" >
    <select id="deps" name="dep" class="form-control"> 
    <option value="0">--- dep list---</option>
    </select>
    </div>    
    </div>
```

thank you everybody i can fix it out like this

```
var re = $.parseJSON(dep);
$.each(re.dep,function(index,value)
{           
$("#deps").append("<option value="+value.DepCod+">"+value.DepLocNam+"</option>");
});
```

Comment: The `for` loop + jQuery `each` combo looks a bit suspicious

Comment: remove the for loop, just $.each will do `$.each(re, function (index, value) {
                $("#deps").append("<option value=" + value.DepCod + ">" + value.DepLocNam + "</option>");
                //  alert(value[dep][0].DepCod);
            });`

Comment: it doesn't work and list of select box display undefined(1data)

Comment: i just edit my code like $.each(re, function(index, value) {
   $("#deps").append('<option value="' + value.DepCod + '">' + value.DepLocNam + "</option>");
}); but select box display undefined 1 data in the list

Comment: Please be more careful when posting/editing your code.  Editing out your code mistakes "as we go" renders the older answers obsolete and opens them up to potential down-votes.  Very unfair to those only trying to help.

Comment: Read the last paragraph on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) called "Readable".

Comment: As I tried to explain before, please stop editing your post with the fixed version of the code.  StackOverflow questions and answers are also here to help others in the future, which cannot happen if the reader can't see what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: i'm absolutely sorry Sparky I'm newbie and my english is so poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(re, function(index, value) {
   $("#deps").append('<option value="' + value.DepCod + '">' + value.DepLocNam + "</option>");
}
```

Do you write something like this?

Are you sure, in database table `DEPMST` you have `DepCod` & `DepLocNam` fields?

Comment: yeah i edit like that but doesn't work

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your browser javascript console, at line

var counts = dep.length; 

and get us 're' variable content?

Comment: i just alert(re) i found [object Object]

Comment: Use console.log(re); instead of just alert(re);.

Details there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object

And look to console to get 're' content.

Comment: it show Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Comment: It looks like you added `console.log(obj);` but should add `console.log(re);` Code should look like this: 

`var re = $.parseJSON(dep);
console.log(re);

var counts = dep.length;`

Comment: i can fix it out thank you bros