# show the actual [object Object] in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object of objects and I want to iterate through the objects and show them in the browser; I have the following code, but it just shows me [object Object][object Object][object Object]; how can I show the actual objects?

```
my my_obj looks like:

{
    "User": {
        "description": "A user."
    },
    "Media": {
        "description": "A media ."
    }
}

var output = "";
for (var key in my_obj) {
    output += my_obj[key];
}
response.send(output);
```

Thanks

Comment: try `console.log` and you can see what the object is in the browser console.

Comment: even in console shows [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: @ajp15243 thanks dude! If you wish put it as an answer and I will mark it as solved! Thanks again

Comment: try `console.log` in the developer console of your browser

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957537/1883647) is essentially a duplicate of yours.

The [accepted answer for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957633/1883647) uses the [`console` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) to print the contents of the object to the JavaScript debugging console in the browser's developer tools (usually accessible with F12).  You can typically interact with the object, expanding and collapsing its properties, in the logged output in the console.

```
console.log(my_obj);
```

However, this doesn't provide an easy way to print the contents of the object to the webpage. For that, you can follow the above-linked question's [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293047/1883647), which uses the [`JSON` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), specifically it's `stringify` method.

```
var my_obj_str = JSON.stringify(my_obj);
```

This method returns a stringified version of your object (i.e. it will appear like an object literal), which can then either be logged to the console like above (although it would be a string, not an interactive object!), or put into the webpage in whatever manner you like putting strings into webpage content.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use  JSON.stringify() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify