# Node.js parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

should be a simple one but I can't find an answer..

I am console logging some parsed Json but it only shows one level and does not show the deeper objects in the log..

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0',
  result: 
   [ { marketId: '1.118750017',
       marketName: 'Match Odds',
       marketStartTime: '2015-05-12T15:30:00.000Z',
       totalMatched: 52.32,
       runners: [Object],
       eventType: [Object],
       competition: [Object],
       event: [Object] } ],
  id: 1 }
```

How do I log and expand on the items showing as objects above. I know they exist but can't print them out to the screen.

code is simply;

```
var response = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(response);
```

If I console log str I get all the data in a not very readable format.

Thanks

Comment: console.dir() instead of console.log()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: that produces the same output in the terminal....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the util.inspect method with these options:

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(response, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
    JSON.stringify(response);