# Can't figure out correct way to use body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am writing the backend of a simple app using node and express. This is how I have structured my code:

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = require('./router')(app);

app.listen(80,function(){
    console.log("Started on PORT 80");
})
module.exports = app;
```

Under subdirectory /router I have
index.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
};
```

Under /router/routes I have
login.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body.user;
    console.log("Handler for /login called");
    console.log("The username is: "+ user);
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am testing using

```
curl -X POST -d '{"user":"alpha", "password":"beta"}' http:my-app-ip/login --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

The console prints `The username is: undefined` instead of the value for key user.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try moving all of the cURL options *before* the URL? I'm wondering if the header isn't being set ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to get a string representation of the value, or use `console.dir(req.body)` which outputs `util.inspect(req.body)` to stdout.

Comment: console.dir worked. It now prints { user: 'alpha', password: 'beta}

So the app is getting the correct text. But the body parser still doesnt work. I have modified the code to add the lines    var user = req.body.user; console.log(user) but it prints undefined

Comment: I have edited my original question to reflect the code changes and the current output.
When I had the same code all in one file, it worked fine. But when I split it like this the body parser stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. The [Object object] you see is due to the console.log.

Try this: `console.log(req.body.user)`. My guess is that you'll see the correct output.

Have a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object) though

Comment: didn't work. This is what i was trying before. It prints undefined when i do this