# How to determine what javascript object has been returned

Tags: javascript

In instances when a javascript function returns an object, what is a good way of determining what exactly it is that you got?

If I do this:

```
alert(myFunction(this));
```

And I get back simply `[object Object]`, what are some useful things that I can do to determine what it is?

Comment: Is this just for debugging, or would you actually want the program to know some details about the object?

Comment: see story http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if debugging don't use alert, use the console instead

```
console.log(myFunction(this));
console.dir(myFunction(this));
console.error(myFunction(this));
//etc
```

If you are trying to determine the type of object and do something depending on what it is use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) or [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Using typeof

```
var something = myFunction(this);
if(typeof something === "string"){
   console.log("It's a string");
}
```

Using instanceof

```
var something = myFunction(this);
if(something instanceof HTMLElement){
    console.log("It's an html element");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log` method to display data in your console instead of alert :

```
console.log(myFunction(this));
```

In some browsers you can use `console.dir`, so you can get more details about the object :

```
console.dir(myFunction(this));
```

---

**Example**

```js
var myObj = {foo: 'bar'}

alert(myObj);

console.log(myObj); //Check your console, you can see the object
console.dir(myObj); //You can see the object with more details
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**:
http://jsfiddle.net/6daL71zd/

You can use:

**1)**

```
console.log(myFunction(this))
```

to print out to the console

*(this can be accessed via your browser's developer tools...the 'F12' key on your keyboard should open it)*

**2)**

```
var output = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(myFunction(this)));
document.body.appendChild(output);
```

to print out on the page.