# How to print all properties/values in an object at once. JS

Tags: javascript, oop, object

So let's say that I have this:

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var car1 = new Car("VW", "Bug", 2012);
var car2 = new Car("Toyota", "Prius", 2004);

document.write(car1.make, car1.model, car1.year);
document.write(car2.make, car2.mocel, car2.year);
```

Is there a cleaner way to write out all of the properties/values of objects? Thank!

Comment: What is "cleaner"? What is not "clean" about the way you are doing it now?

Comment: What is this for? If you want to debug your code, use your browser's developer tools and `console.log`.

Comment: you should at least encapsulate it to say something like document.write(car1.toString()) and implement toString() for your object.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to serialize an object and easily log its properties:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(car1))
```

Answer (score 2):

To enumerate all the properties of an object in JavaScript:

```
for (aProperty in yourObject) {
    // do what needed
    // in case you want just to print it:
    console.log(aProperty + "has value: " + yourObject[aProperty]);
}
```

However, if you just meant to print the object to the console, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use a simple `for` loop to loop through all the properties, but that means you get all the properties that were set in it's ancestors as well, so you can use `Object.hasOwnProperty` to verify that this property was set for itself and not inherited, and print out the relevant properties (or do something with them).

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var bmw = new Car('VW','Cruiser',1989);
var output = document.getElementById('output');

for(property in bmw) 
  if(bmw.hasOwnProperty(property))  
    output.innerHTML += property + ': ' + bmw[property] + '<br />'
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Object.keys/Object.values and then suitably adding forEach loop to access the keys/values?

1. Object.keys(Car).forEach(prop => console.log(prop))     //it will print keys of the the Car object
2. Object.values(Car).forEach(prop=>console.log(prop))     // it will print values of the Car object

But it won't give desired output in case of nested Object. So go on with normaml forEach loop or traditional looping method...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[MDN documentation will help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

You can use

```
for(aVariable in yourObject){
   console.log(aVariable);
}
```

This way, you can see every attribute of an object

Comment: This is a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: yes, this code is common, and we posted very close to each other, however, I have added a source, and even eddited to be closer to what you wrotte.... but both our answers fit the question