# JS Object elements printing in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jscharts

How can I print object array elements values in a web page using `document.write` ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

 <script>

   var data =  [
           {
             "metadata" : {
                 "names":["times","values","types"],
                 "types":["time","linear","ordinal"]
             },
             "data": [
             ["1141237500000",4.216,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237560000",2.4130,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237620000",3.4230,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237680000",2.4560,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237500000",2.37130,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237560000",2.35840,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237620000",0.32690,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237680000",10.30980,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237500000",13.800,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237560000",16.400,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237620000",25.400,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237680000",13.800,"Global_intensity"],
           ],
           }
         ];

   document.write( data["data"] );

 </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: `document.write(JSON.stringify(data["data"] ) );`

Comment: console.log(data)  will be more dscriptive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @SunnySoni OP asked about printing it to a webpage. In that case, `console.log()` can't be used.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj right, but most possibly he would have been debugging it so console will help more.

Comment: @SunnySoni yes, right.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj that outputs "undefined"

Comment: Please check my updated code. I have ouputted only "data" property of this array.

Comment: Yeah , that's worked. I couldn't figure out that was you . sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your object in a string form, which can the be printed on your html page with `document.write`.

```js
var data =  [
           {
             "metadata" : {
                 "names":["times","values","types"],
                 "types":["time","linear","ordinal"]
             },
             "data": [
             ["1141237500000",4.216,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237560000",2.4130,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237620000",3.4230,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237680000",2.4560,"Global_active_power"],
             ["1141237500000",2.37130,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237560000",2.35840,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237620000",0.32690,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237680000",10.30980,"Voltage"],
             ["1141237500000",13.800,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237560000",16.400,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237620000",25.400,"Global_intensity"],
             ["1141237680000",13.800,"Global_intensity"],
           ],
           }
         ];
             
var innerDataValues = data[0].data;

// document.write( JSON.stringify(data ) );
for( var i = 0; i < innerDataValues.length; i++ )
{
  var value = innerDataValues[i];
  document.write( value[0] + "<br />"); // 0 for timestamp
}
```

Comment: It could be the answer? I con't understand those question 
why he don't write any description?

Comment: @HengSopheak Yes, because in its current form i.e. `document.write( data );` it will not print contents of the Object but `object Object`.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses , actually what I need to know is how to go through with data object data key("data":) elements

Comment: @IT14064432FirnasA.M can you share the expected output please. That will be helpful.

Comment: go through the data object data key values , that means ["1141237500000",4.216,"Global_active_power"]  , [...] etc.. and select only needed some timestamp arrays. (by if condition).I need to to know how to traverse through the data values and select only from it .

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj got it ?

Comment: need something like this , document.write(JSON.stringify(data[0].data[0].times) );

Comment: Yeap , basically need to traverse through each and every timestamp one by one.

Comment: I got it,  document.write(JSON.stringify((data[0].data[0])[0]));

Comment: Yes, like that. But you need to iterate through the array using `for` or some other loop. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes ,great.Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, how to compare two timestamps in javascript ? `if(((innerDataValues[0])[0]) >= start1.getTime()) ` . The greater than or less than operators not working for timestamp values ( epoch time) .

Comment: @IT14064432FirnasA.M You can try with this code: `if((( parseInt(innerDataValues[0])[0]) ) >= start1.getTime())`. I would recommend opening a new question in case you have additional queries. This will help future users and may get more detailed answers specifically for that issue.

Comment: question limits exceed :( that's the reason. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @IT14064432FirnasA.M Ok then :) . Try that code, may be because the timestamps in your data are in string format, you were not able to compare it to epoch timestamp. I'm not very sure though.

Comment: am I asking easy questions or irrelavant questions here, because of the limit exceeding . Just tell me then I can understand I am wrong . my bad :(

Comment: @IT14064432FirnasA.M No, I don't think that is so. You can check the more probable reasons here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219683/question-limit-exceeded-but-i-havent-asked-any