# How to get the output of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

When I add some object in editor &  when I  go to the browser to see the output, it only shows [object object] .Can any one tell me how to see the  output of object in browsers

here is the code

```
// alert('Hello world ');
var contacts = new Array();
var add = function(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  this.email = email;
};
contacts[contacts.length] = new add("imtiaz", "ahmed", "01794705874", "imtiaz@gmail.com");
contacts[contacts.length] = new add("johny", "bob", "998978788", "bob@gmail.com");
document.write("</br>" + contacts);
```

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: "Go to the browser to see the output"... what browser? What output? What code?

Comment: This is a [Duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Please provide some code for us to help you solve this problem. What does the object look like and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say if you have an object like this.

```
 var Somebody = {
 name: "John Smith",
 age: 120};
```

To print it in the browser you can use JSON like this.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(Somebody, null, 3));
```

Comment: Celaro it worked but why did u add null and 3 ? It also worked without them

Comment: Like it states here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) stringily takes 3 arguments, the object, a optional function to filter the properties of the object, and the number of space between each output

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(yourObject);`. It will display on your browser's console.

Comment: yeah it shows in browsers console but not in the main place and I have provided the code please see

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(contacts));
```