# Javascript: How to display everything an object contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, text, uwp

I am using this piece of Javascript to get the Clipboard content insde of a UWP App:

```
var content = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent();
var text = content.getTextAsync();
```

However, if I display `text` in my view it shows `[object Object]` even though the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackageView_GetTextAsync) say the method `getTextAsync` returns text.

How can I see what is inside the object, without expecting something specific?

Comment: log `JSON.stringify(text)`

Comment: how about `JSON.stringify(content.getTextAsync());`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4293047/6048928

Comment: Ah, that explains everything, I get this: `{"operation":{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var text = JSON.stringify(content.getTextAsync());`should solve the issue.