# Returned objects from ionic native - Sim

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to fetch the device phone number of the mobile phone on which the ionic app is installed  I am using
 (ionic cordova plugin add **cordova-plugin-sim**)
I do get an object as response,
  What i need to find is what are the elements of the abject as i need to parse it.
Code below
The HTML file

```
<ion-content padding>
<button ion-button full (click)="getDeviceInfo()">Password Reset</button>
  <ion-item>
    {{deviceInfo}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

The typescript file

```
getDeviceInfo(){
this.sim.getSimInfo().then((info)=>{
  this.deviceInfo = info;
  console.log(this.deviceInfo);
  alert(this.deviceInfo);
}, Error=>{
  alert('Could not capture device information!');
});
}
```

The response i get is an object
[Object][Object]
I tried looking at the log cat in android studio but did not find anything

How do i parse this?
Any advise will be great help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the object into a string using `JSON.stringify`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.deviceInfo));
```