# JS log object why is showing [object Object]

Tags: javascript, logging

In JS, if I log a string to the console it is not showing properly ?

```
console.log(uniqueProducts); //
console.log("uniqueProducts:"+uniqueProducts);
```

result

```
[ { country: 'Russia', launches: 32 },
  { country: 'US', launches: 23 },
  { country: 'China', launches: 16 } ]
uniqueProducts:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
map
```

So why is [object Object] shown instead of the value? It is like it changes type with string appended?

Comment: You are concatenating an object to string

Comment: And concatenating any to a string converts that into a string. An Object when converted to a string is `[object Object]`, so you first have to parse the object itself,

Comment: Related: [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957537)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are concatenating an `object` to `string`

You can console a string and an object by separating it by comma(`,`)

you can `console.log("uniqueProducts:", uniqueProducts );`

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to concatenate an object with a string. You can fix it one of two ways:

1. Remove `+` from the log call:

```js
console.log("uniqueProducts:", uniqueProducts);
```

2. You can use `JSON.stringify` to print the object as JSON:

```js
console.log("uniqueProducts:", JSON.stringify(uniqueProducts));
```

Answer (score 4):

`+` concatenates `strings` but `object` is not a string.

Use `console.dir(obj)` to display the content of the `object`.