# why is react axios call returning empty result?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a Spring Boot application running on the backend on localhost:8080.  The front end is react app on localhost:3000.  I'm trying to call a url from the backend but result is empty.  Why?

If I call the backend url directly in a browser like this:

> http://localhost:8080/appointments

I see the data come in ok (in the form of a view template) that looks like this:
[image]

But when I call the same url from my react app like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    (
        async () => {
            const result = await axios("http://localhost:8080/appointments");
            console.log("result="+result);
            //setData(result.data);
        }
    )();
},
```

then the console shows and empty result:

> result=[object Object]

Sorry if this is a basic question.  I'm new to react.

Comment: [How to log objects in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47842644/1218980)

Comment: Thank you Emile!  I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention get request in axios.

Try this way:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    (
        async () => {
            const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/appointments");
            console.log("result =", result);
            //setData(result.data);
        }
    )();
},
```

Also, when you `console.log("result="+result);` you are concatenating an object to string, instead use `console.log("result =", result);`

Comment: I think I knew that once and forgot.  Thank you!  Unfortunately, it isn't returning what I was expecting.  It is returning the entire html table, not just the data.  I'll need to dig deeper.