# Getting an [object Object] instead of actual data in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm dispatching an action, which gets a response from a route in this format :

```
res.json({
  token,
  user: {
    id: user.id,
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
  },
})
```

The promise does resolve and the new user is saved to the DB. 
But on the reducer, which looks like this :

```
case ADD_USER:
  console.log(`payload is ${action.payload.user}`)
  return {
    ...state,
    users: [...state.users, action.payload.user],
  }
```

The payload I get in chrome console is this :

> payload is [object Object]

Which should look like this :

```
user: {
  id: '5ea737af99a72f29d4864843',
  email: 'ssdjksd@dkskd.com',
  password: '$2a$10$wqVQaOFTTD5nTB/eQN79xuSlFy0gQ8kgz3QKuB86BVs1ke6MMPFX6'
}
```

The data is stored correctly in state and I can see it in Redux Dev tools,

But how can I see the console.log right too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS log object why is showing \[object Object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842644/js-log-object-why-is-showing-object-object)

Comment: Thank u. Didn't know you cant concatenate a string with an object

Comment: @apollo24 you can concatenate an object to a string, but unless you define a custom `toString` function on that object, you'll get `[object Object]`, which is the default string representation of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to `console.log('payload', action.payload.user);`