# Unable to print objects in console window debugger

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, debugging

I tried to print the objects in console window as the following but  I am not getting the object instead it is saying "Undefined". Any suggestions?

```
var details = [
    {
        name:"Anita", 
        age:"20"
    },{
        name: "Helen", 
        age:"21"
    }
];

console.log(details) //undefined

console.log(details) //undefined

console.table(details) //undefined
```

Comment: It would help if you show us how you are trying to print the object - `console.log(xxx)`?

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object

Comment: I tried to print like this console.log(details) in chrome window...But it is showing undefined instead of displaying my object in details. @ Mawg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F12, to show the developer console.

Navigate to the source file where you are doing that `console.log(details);` left click at the left of that line (on the line number) to create a [breakpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint).

Reload your page and the code will run to that breakpoint and stop. Now you can right click on `details` in the code and chose `evaluate in console`.

If it still shows undefined, that is your problem.

You have now learned a new and very useful skill. Get into the habit of using the developer console. Breakpoints are your friends. You can evaluate & change variables and see the call stack + more