# Store Image in Variable

Tags: javascript

I have this image element with an id. I am trying to store it as a variable so that I can use it. I have my code but when I run it, instead of a display image, it shows me [object Object]. Please, how do I store images in a variable and gain access to it?

html:

```
<img width="100" height="100" id="image"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function myTest(){
  var image =  $("#image").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,");
}
```

Comment: you can try to store image src as a string in a variable will that works for you?

Comment: Your script (or HTML?) there doesn't look valid, can you post a clearer example of what you have so far?

Comment: Are you trying to convert an image from a source like `image.jpg` into base64-encoded string?

Comment: _"when I run it, instead of a display image, it shows me [object Object]"_ <- nothing in your code would display anything at all. What **exactly** is producing `[object Object]`?

Comment: Are you trying to **replace** the `src` attribute of your image with the base64 string image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: alert(image[0].src);

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want the actual base64 data of the image to use later, and not just the `src`, then you'd do something like

```
fetch(srcOfImg)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const newImg = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
      newImg.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
```