# Why the additional properties of "String#match / RegExp#exec" are not in the returned result?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

The following statement is written in [the documentation of `String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value):

> if the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. In this case, **the returned item will have additional properties as described below**.

Then, below the "*Additional properties*" subchapter is stated this:

> As explained above, some results contain additional properties as described below.
>
> - `groups`: An array of named capturing groups or `undefined` if no named capturing groups were defined. See Groups and Ranges for more information.
> - `index`: The index of the search at which the result was found.
> - `input`: A copy of the search string.

However, when I execute the [`Using match()` example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Using_match()), the `console.log` output doesn't seem to be what is expected in the snippet comments.

```js
var str = 'For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1';
var re = /see (chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);

// logs [ 'see Chapter 3.4.5.1',
//        'Chapter 3.4.5.1',
//        '.1',
//        index: 22,
//        input: 'For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1' ]

// 'see Chapter 3.4.5.1' is the whole match.
// 'Chapter 3.4.5.1' was captured by '(chapter \d+(\.\d)*)'.
// '.1' was the last value captured by '(\.\d)'.
// The 'index' property (22) is the zero-based index of the whole match.
// The 'input' property is the original string that was parsed.
```

Why the additional properties of `String#match` (or `RegExp#exec`, as the result is said to be same) are not in the returned result?

Is this feature planned but not implemented today?

---

**Found out that's the SE Overflow's snippet console that doesn't output these properties.**

An issue has been opened on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385652/why-doesnt-the-code-snippets-console-display-string-key-properties-of-an-array).

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: In fact, I particulary want to access the `index` property stated by the documentation.

Comment: The additional properties are not available when `.match` is used with a `g`-regex. That is why `matchAll` was added recently: to keep info of each match when use `g` modifier in regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There's no `g` qualifier (`/see (chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i`) hence the question

Comment: Current `found` in Chrome is `(3) ["see Chapter 3.4.5.1", "Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".1", index: 22, input: "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1", groups: undefined]` - it is in line with the current docs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For me (FF67, x64) its: `[ "see Chapter 3.4.5.1", "Chapter 3.4.5.1", ".1" ]`

Comment: Found out that's the SE Overflow's snippet console that doesn't output these properties.

Comment: @Andreas See https://imgur.com/a/LNzjlGS. All expected properties are there. FF regex does not support named capturing groups, thus, `groups` is missing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, in the console they are visible, but not in the snippet. I should have had a look in the console first...

Comment: So, there is no issue in the first place. Just get each match and access the required properties available. Changed close reason to [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You're right, that's not an actual issue. Like Andreas I should have check the browser's console at first. But it seems that the snippet feature need a little update.

Comment: Yeah, maybe worth posting on meta.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Done. Added the link in my post.