# Why is my JavaScript output weird when I am implementing .match regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

So, i been getting this kind of output lately when im coding but i just want to make sure its normal or maybe im doing something wrong.  Here is a simple code.. maybe it has to do with regex.

my console says " (1) ['a', index: 1, input: 'karina', groups: undefined] "

```js
function reg(s) {
    reg = /[aeiou]/;
    console.log(s.match(reg));
}
reg("turtle");
```

Comment: Your input in your example doesn't match your console output. There's not enough information here to know what exactly you're finding to be weird, but everything seems in order besides your example using `turtle` versus `karina`.

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: It is correct it checks if the string has any matching character to your values of aeiou and the index of the first one and will return null otherwise.

Comment: Redefining a function while inside that function will almost never do what you want. Anecdotally I did that once, on purpose, but never ever do that.

Comment: If you use `reg("turtle");` and then get `['a', index: 1, input: 'karina'` you have an issue but you are not showing the right code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392943/why-the-additional-properties-of-stringmatch-regexpexec-are-not-in-the-ret

Comment: `.match` without the `g` flag on your RegExp returns an Array of the first match followed by parenthetical subpatterns.

Comment: sorry guys. I didnt wait it to show "karina" so i changed it to "turtle" the input should also be "turtle" @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Then edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine. The .match() method will compare the string and the RegEx that you defined and return an array with the first match it finds and at what index it happens.

If you want to get back an array with all of the results and without the other information, all you need to do is add a "g" at the end of your RegEx. Your function should look like this:

```js
function reg(s) {
    reg = /[aeiou]/g;
    console.log(s.match(reg));
}

reg('turtle');
```

The "g" at the end, will make so that .match() will look and grab all of the occurrences in the string that you are checking, instead of just the first one.

Comment: You should put `reg('turtle');` at the end of your snippet so the OP can see the output.